# PhoneGap Android

Tags: javascript, html, css, android, cordova

I am new to phonegap and android , i wanted to know how to access/make database through 
javascript. and the second thing i want to ask is how to make Graphs just using html, css and javascript.

Every information is thankfully accepted.

Comment: I have tried to get data through javascript and jQtouch using localStorage and sessionStorage.

Answer (score 1):

First off, it is best to post each question separately.

To answer both your questions: the easy way is to use Google API's. With the [Database API](http://code.google.com/apis/gears/api_database.html) of Google Gears, you can "persistently store an application user's data" locally, and with the Google Chart Tools you can create graphs by simpy calling a URL with the right parameters. Both should work from any browser, including mobile.

Comment: thnks for the information and suggestion.

can i use localStorage() and sessionStorage() for DATABASE using android.